# leave datetime picker returns 1 / 1 / 0001 12:00:00 AM in c#

Tags: c#, datetime, nul

I define this in my class

```
 public DateTime? LineCheckSubmitDateTime { set; get; }
```

I need to initialize this variable using my `gridview`

[image]

But sometimes i need to leave this value to be null ,But when i leave it it returns `1 / 1 / 0001 12:00:00 AM`

so here is my code :

```
 newObj.LineCheckSubmitDateTime = (Convert.ToDateTime(gridViewDetails.GetRowCellValue(rowHandle, "LineCheckSubmitDateTime"))==DateTime.Parse("1 / 1 / 0001 12:00:00 AM") ) ?   Convert.ToDateTime(gridViewDetails.GetRowCellValue(rowHandle, "LineCheckSubmitDateTime")):null;
```

So two questions:

1:this code returns this error :

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line
Error   CS0173  Type of conditional expression cannot be determined because there is no implicit conversion between 'DateTime' and '<null>'
```

2:do you have better solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is because you have to explicitly cast at least one of the operand of conditional operator to  `DateTime?`

A better way to do it would be to compare it with `DateTime.MinValue` instead of converting minimum date string to `DateTime`, and also cache the converted value and then use it in the conditional operator instead of converting it twice.

```
var tempDateConverted = Convert.ToDateTime(gridViewDetails.GetRowCellValue(rowHandle, "LineCheckSubmitDateTime"));
 newObj.LineCheckSubmitDateTime = tempDateConverted == DateTime.MinValue ?
                                    null : (DateTime?) tempDateConverted;
```

You can also *explicitly* cast `null` to `DateTime?` in the above statement.

I am not sure about the `LineCheckSubmitDateTime` control in `GridView`, here is a possibility that its value is already a `DateTime` object , returned inside an `object`. You can also try:

```
object obj = gridViewDetails.GetRowCellValue(rowHandle, "LineCheckSubmitDateTime");
newObj.LineCheckSubmitDateTime = (DateTime?) obj;
```

With the above code, you don't have to call `Convert.ToDateTime`.

Comment: @EhsanAkbar, made a mistake in code, instead of `DateTime?` I had `DateTime`. Code is modified now. It should be fine.

Comment: Habib unfortunately i have same error do you change the code?

Comment: You shouldn't get that error again, and yes I have changed the code.

Comment: In fact i exactly copied you code into my vs,but i have the same error .

Comment: comment out these lines in VS. clean , Rebuild your code, once successfully build, then uncomment these lines in your code and try again. There could be an issue with the visual studio build.

Comment: Now it works without syntax error but  i run it again and the obj variable initialized with null and in the next line i get null reference error

Comment: @EhsanAkbar, try `newObj.LineCheckSubmitDateTime = (DateTime?) obj;`